# How to create database from existing SQL files in NetBeans?

Tags: sql, netbeans-8, geonetwork

I have downloaded Geonetwork and opened it with NetBeans IDE 8.0.2. In that project, there exists some SQL files. How can i run them or create database based on these files?
Edit:
I have done some more research, and all i need is to connect to H2 driver, but somehow, i can't. It shows me this:
 Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:h2:  using org.h2.Driver (IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\ .lock.db (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)"; "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\ .lock.db" [90031-152]). So, how to fix this?

Comment: update your questions, it is better to follow the question than looking in the answers. I would like to see your java connection url (jdbc url). Should be something like jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/testdb

Comment: I have updated, thanks.

Comment: please provide your jdbc url connection

Answer (score 0):

Go thru this document and you will have your database, Derby will give you a quick setup for your need.

[**NetBeans - Working with the Java DB (Derby) Database**](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html)

Just remember to open your geonetwork sql files, from the file browser navigate to the location of the saved sql file and click open...

If you have other database already installed, such as MySQL, Oracle etc. You can check the documentation [here (see database section)](https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/tools.html)

Comment: You have answered my question, but after you answered i have realized that this is not what i need. I have explained in answer above.